# Read text file saved in SD card line by line

Tags: arduino

I have `data.txt` file saved in  SD card containing values of variables required for driving 3 stepper motors. I want to read `data.txt` file line by line, split the line by "," and save each values into respective variables. `data.txt` file has data something like this:

`8.24, 5.67, 7.34`
 `3,86, 3.56, 4.49`
  `5.38, 6.29, 3.67`

I want to save value of first integer in `x`, second in `y` and third in `z` and execute the code. Once the code is executed, I want to get next line and load respective values in their respective variables and continue the loop till there is no line left in `data.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

This code for matrix, let change some type that you need

```
public  Matrix loadIntMapData(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        ArrayList<double[]> list = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals("")) {
                //ignore
            } else {
                String[] vs = line.split(",");
                double ints[] = new double[vs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
                    ints[i] = Double.parseDouble(vs[i]);
                }
                list.add(ints);
            }

        }
        double[][] map = new double[list.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            map[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return new Matrix(map);
    }

    public static final void writInteMapData(Matrix matrix, File file) throws IOException {
        double[][] map = matrix.getArray();
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                output.append(Double.toString(map[i][j]));
                if (j != map[i].length - 1) {
                    output.append(",");
                }
            }

            if (i != map.length - 1) {
                output.append("\r\n");
            }
        }


        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(output.toString());
        writer.close();
    }
```